# Get Elements by Node Type

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing

Most web browsers keep white space and new lines between XML document elements in `TEXT_NODE`s.  I don't like that.  I am parsing an XML document, modifying it, then serializing it back into a String.  I would like that String to not contain the extra white space or new line characters between the nodes.  For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<bookshelf>
    <book>
        <author>John Doe</author>
        <title>My Favorite Book</title>
    </book>
    <book>
        <author>Jane Doe</author>
        <title>My Second Favorite Book</title>
    </book>
</bookshelf>
```

Should turn into:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><bookshelf><book><author>John Doe</author><title>My Favorite Book</title></book><book><author>Jane Doe</author><title>My Second Favorite Book</title></book></bookshelf>
```

Mostly, I'm just trying to keep the size of my XML document down to a minimum, since it's often megabytes in size, and human readability isn't a major concern of mine since this document is both produced and processed by a machine.

I know that I could parse through every node in the document, test its node type, and if it is a `TEXT_NODE` (type 3), `remove()`.  The performance of my application would suffer from this approach, however, considering the sheer number of nodes in the document.  I'm looking for any alternative approaches that can create an array of all elements by their node type, for example.  Or any other ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: I should also note that some nodes in this document contain CDATA nodes with raw HTML in them, making REGEXP a difficult approach.

Comment: Are you transforming this on the server side or the client side? Most parsers (that I've used in Java, Perl, ObjC) serialize *without* spaces as default. A simple XSLT stylesheet containing only an identity transformation + the `<xsl:strip-spaces>` element could be used to strip all the spaces between tags.

Comment: @helderdarocha I'm parsing client-side. Using XSLTs is an interesting idea, though... I'll check it out. Thanks!